# How to make Safari-Bars visible after hiding in Fullscreenmode on Mobile-Safari

Tags: ios, html, ipad, mobile-safari

I will display some documents(.pdf .docx .xls ...) with the build-in viewer of MobileSafari on my ipad.

The Mainpage has this `<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">` to hide the SafariBars in fullscreenmode. It all works fine.

Now i will show the documents in a new window with `window.open("test.pdf")`.
The problem is, i cant close the window because the statusbars are hidden.

Is there a chance to make the Bars visible or close/get back with events etc?